# Apache beam spark /flink runner not getting executed in EMR(Access files from GCS)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-beam, apache-spark-2.0, apache-beam-io

I have an apache beam pipeline to index some data to elasticsearch. I was trying to use spark or Flink runner to run the job in AWS EMR. When I tried to run the job on a stand-alone spark on local setup, pipeline works with source files in the local disk, however, when I read the file from GCS it's not working. It is the same when I am running in the EMR cluster.

The configs that I set on the Hadoop core-site.xml
as EMR config

```
{
    "Classification": "core-site",
    "Properties": {
      "fs.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem",
      "fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS",
      "fs.gs.project.id": "data-warehouse",
      "google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable": "true",
      "fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile": "/home/hadoop/utils/key.json"
    }
  }
```

Also, GCS-connector jar is in the spark jar path and hadoop jar path

The pom file of the maven for the pipeline

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>IndexToEs</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <beam.version>2.22.0</beam.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-exec-plugin.version>1.6.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.company.beam.IndexToEs</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-exec-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
<!--      <scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-flink -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-flink_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
      <version>hadoop2-1.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

There is no error but EMR shows task com[pleted but the pipeline has not run.

I could not figure out if its an apache beam problem or cluster config problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Apache beam sdk uses gsutil to access the GCS files. As per flink documentation, hadoop connectors were responsible for any other files system access, but in the case of apache beam using flink runner the data is read using gsutil and fed into the downstream. So I installed google could SDK and activated the service account.